# Square root using Newton's method with recursion c#

Tags: c#, recursion

I'm trying to calculate the square root of the number 12345. I'm new to programming, and need help with the bottom so I don't receive the exeption "Stack overflow".

```cs
public static decimal Sqrt(int number, decimal root)
{
    return Sqrt(number, root - ((root * root) - number) / (2 * root));
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{

    decimal root = Sqrt(12345, 10M);

    Console.WriteLine(root);

}
```

Comment: A recursive function like `Sqrt` needs halting criteria. When the halting criteria are true, it should just return what it has instead of continuing with the recursion. I believe for this algorithm you halt when the newly computed value is within some tolerance of the last computed value. You will have to decide what the tolerance is and add a check to the `Sqrt` function.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow#Infinite_recursion):

> The most-common cause of stack overflow is excessively deep or
> infinite recursion, in which a function calls itself so many times
> that the space needed to store the variables and information
> associated with each call is more than can fit on the stack.
>
> An example of infinite recursion in C.

```
int foo()
{

    return foo();

}
```

> The function foo, when it is invoked, continues to invoke itself, allocating additional space on the stack
> each time, until the stack overflows resulting in a segmentation
> fault. However, some compilers implement tail-call optimization,
> allowing infinite recursion of a specific sort—tail recursion—to occur
> without stack overflow. This works because tail-recursion calls do not
> take up additional stack space.

You missed a check. Your code is [infinite recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop#Infinite_recursion), since there is no way to escape from recursion.

The line

```cs
return Sqrt(number, root - ((root * root) - number) / (2 * root));
```

will result in another call for `Sqrt` method, and it will result in another call for `Sqrt` method, which will result in .... SO when it stops and return proper result?!

Anyway, if you add a single if statement it will work correctly.

```cs
public static decimal Sqrt(int number, decimal root)
{
    if (Math.Abs(root * root - number) <= 0.00000000001M)
        return root;

    return Sqrt(number, root - ((root * root) - number) / (2 * root));
}

// Usage:
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Sqrt(4, someDecimal));
}
```

If you use

`if (root * root == number)`

instead of

`if (Math.Abs(root * root - number) <= 0.00000000001M)`

, your code will only support perfect squares.